# Submit Piece with Permissions "False" not updated to Draft Mode. Only Available in Live Mode

Tags: apostrophe-cms

This project is using Apostrophe-Workflow . Therefore , I created my own custom module for comment system with permissions false (Follow this [comment system](https://github.com/stuartromanek/apostrophe-comment-system) but adjust the piece myself for non-logged user submission). It was successful and submitted to database with non-logged user viewer. However , when I logged in and see pieces items submitted from non-logged user , it's empty/isn't there. And apostrophe-workflow asking me to **commit** without non-logged user submitted . To be clear , in **Live Mode** , I can see submitted comments. But in **Draft Mode** , nothing. And it prompts me to commit the changes (Which means to commit/delete non-logged user comments). Here is my piece and piece-widgets .

### Here is an example for **Live Mode** *(Successful submitted comment for non-logged user - Public)* :

[image: Live Mode]

### But When view in **Draft Mode** , you can't see the public comments and it asking for commit without public comments (When click commit , the button does not disappear) :

[image]

In `modules/comments/index.js` :

```
module.exports = {
    extend : 'apostrophe-pieces',
    name : 'comments',
    label : 'Comment Form',
    alias : 'commentForm',
    pluralLabel : 'All Comments',
    addFields : [
    {
        name: 'comments',
        label: 'Comments',
        type: 'array',
        sortify : true,
        schema: [
        {
            name: 'date',
            label: 'Date',
            type: 'date'
        },
        {
            name: 'readerName',
            label: 'Reader\'s Name',
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        }, {
            name: 'comment',
            label: 'Comment',
            type: 'string',
            textarea: true,
            required: true
        }]
    }],
    arrangeFields : [{
            name: 'comment',
            label: 'Comment',
            fields: ['comments']
        },
        {
            name: 'config',
            label: 'Comment Configuration',
            fields: ['title', 'slug', 'published', 'tags'],
            last: true
        }
    ],
    permissionsFields: false,
    construct: function (self, options) {

        self.addTask('update', 'Update Cursor for comment with data permissions false', function (apos, argv, callback) {
            var year = new Date().getFullYear();
            var month = (new Date().getMonth() < 12) ? "0" + new Date().getMonth() : new Date().getMonth();
            var day = (new Date().getDay() < 10) ? "0" + new Date().getDay() : new Date().getDay();
            var date = [
                [year],
                [month],
                [day]
            ];
            date.join('-');
            console.log("Array to string" , date.join('-'));

            const req = apos.tasks.getAnonReq();

            const idPiece = self.generate(1);

            self.apos.docs.getManager('comments').find(req)
                .criteria({
                    _id: idPiece
                })
                .sort({
                    updatedAt: 1
                })
                .log(true)
                .toArray(function (err, docs) {
                    if (err) {
                        return callback(null);
                    }
                    // fetch comment req.body
                    // generate new commentId

                    var comment = {
                        _id: self.apos.utils.generateId(),
                        date: date,
                        readerName: 'Reader Amin',
                        comment: 'Some comment'
                    };

                    // Hack method - Make it published when sucessful update
                    docs.published = true;

                    docs.forEach(doc => {
                        doc.comments.push(comment);
                        console.log("Success");
                        return self.apos.modules['comments']
                            .update(req, doc, {
                                permissions: false
                            }, function () {
                                console.log("Doc Update :", doc);
                                // Testing begins
                                self.apos.docs.getManager('comments').find(req)
                                    .criteria({
                                        _id: idPiece
                                    })
                                    .projection({
                                        title: 1,
                                        slug: 1,
                                        comments: 1,
                                        permissions: 1
                                    })
                                    .toArray((err, doc) => {
                                        if (err) {
                                            return setImmediate(callback);
                                        }
                                        doc.forEach(element => {
                                            console.log("element : ", element);
                                            return callback(null , element);
                                        })
                                    });
                                // End testing
                            });

                        // Then should update the module here using .update()
                    });
                });

        });

        self.addTask('list', 'List all comments with sorting', function (apos, argv, callback) {
            const req = apos.tasks.getAnonReq();
            return self.apos.modules['comments'].find(req)
                .sort({
                    updatedAt: 1
                })
                .projection({
                    title: 1,
                    type: 1,
                    slug: 1,
                    comments: 1,
                    permissions: 1
                })
                .toArray().then((doc) => {
                    // When anything output in array , you can do forEach
                    doc.forEach(element => {
                        // console.log("All comments", doc);
                        console.log("All comments", element);
                        return callback();
                    });
                });
        });

        // Create a post route /modules/comment-form/submit
        self.route('post' , 'submit' , function(req , res){
            // Get by pieces id
            self.apos.docs.getManager('comments').find(req)
            .criteria({
                _id: req.body.pieceId
            })
            .sort({
                createdAt : 1
            })
            .log(true)
            .toArray(function(err , docs){
                // fetch comment req.body
                // generate new commentId

                var comment = {
                    _id : self.apos.utils.generateId(),
                    date : req.body.date ,
                    readerName: req.body.readerName,
                    comment : req.body.comment,
                };

                // get docs . It will output as array.
                // therefore , it's easier to use forEach
                // Hack method - Make it published when sucessful update
                docs.published = true;

                docs.forEach(doc => {
                    doc.comments.push(comment);
                    self.apos.modules['comments']
                        .update(req, doc, {permissions : false}, function () {
                            console.log("Doc Update :" , doc);
                            return res.json({
                                status: 'okay'
                            });
                        });

                    // Then should update the module here using .update()
                });
            });
        });

    }
}
```

In my `/modules/comments-widgets/public/js/always.js` :

```
apos.define('comments-widgets' , {
    extend  :'apostrophe-widgets',
    construct : function(self , options){
        self.play = function($widget , data, options){
            // get form
            $widget.find("[data-button-submit]").on('click' , function(){
                var year = new Date().getFullYear();
                var month = (new Date().getMonth() < 12) ? "0" + new Date().getMonth() : new Date().getMonth();
                var day = (new Date().getDay() < 10) ? "0" + new Date().getDay() : new Date().getDay();
                var date = [
                    [year],
                    [month],
                    [day]
                ];
                date.join('-');
                var data = {
                    pieceId: $widget.find("form").attr("id"),
                    date :date.join('-'),
                    readerName: $widget.find("input[name='readerName']").val(),
                    comment: $widget.find("textarea[name='comment']").val()
                }

                var value = $widget.find("textarea[name='comment']").val();
                console.log("Comment Value" , value);
                $.ajax({
                    url : '/modules/comments/submit',
                    method : 'POST',
                    data : data,
                    success: function (result, status, xhr) {
                        console.log("Success POST" , result);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error){
                        console.log("Failed to POST");
                    }
                }).done(function(msg){
                    apos.change($widget);
                });

            });

        }
    }
})
```

In `/modules/comments-widgets/views/widget.html` :

```
{% for piece in data.widget._pieces %}
<form class="comment-widget" id="{{ piece._id }}" data-apos-pieces-submit-form>
<h4 class="Mont-Bold leave-comment">Leave a comment</h4>
    <input type="text" name="readerName" placeholder="Reader's Name">
    {# Must use fieldset with data.name on schema.name object #}
    <textarea name="comment" id="textarea-comment" cols="10" placeholder="Write a comment"></textarea>
<button class="submit" data-button-submit>Submit</button>
<div class="thank-you" data-apos-pieces-submit-thank-you>
    <h1>Done</h1>
</div>
</form>
<div class="comment-container">
    {% for piece in piece.comments %}
    <div class="comment-piece">
        <h4 class="reader-comment Mont-Heavy">{{ piece.readerName }} <span class="Mont-Regular" style="color : #0F58FF; font-size :14px ; letter-spacing : 0.20px; line-height : 19px;">- {{ piece.date | date("Do MMM YYYY") }}</span></h4>
        <p class="comment-paragraph Mont-Regular">{{ piece.comment }}</p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

---

## Step By Step on how I create add Comment Piece on Page

1.Create/Add Comment Form & Add a Title
[image: Add Comment Form]
[image: Create Comment Form]

2.On Pieces-Pages , Select Comment Widget & Browse Individually
[image: Browse]

3.Select my comment piece that created the title and DONE !
[image: Select Comment]

---

## Updated

This code does not work . It somehow successful update but both live and draft are not updated . Here is my code using your solution :

```
self.route('post', 'submit', function (req, res) {
      // Get by pieces id

        // get docs . It will output as array.
        // therefore , it's easier to use forEach
        // Hack method - Make it published when sucessful update

        self.apos.docs.getManager('comments').find(req)
            .criteria({
                _id: req.body.pieceId
            })
            .sort({
                createdAt: 1
            })
            .log(true)
            .toArray(function (err, docs) {
                // fetch comment req.body
                // generate new commentId

                var comment = {
                    _id: self.apos.utils.generateId(),
                    date: req.body.date,
                    readerName: req.body.readerName,
                    comment: req.body.comment,
                };

                // get docs . It will output as array.
                // therefore , it's easier to use forEach
                // Hack method - Make it published when sucessful update
                docs.published = true;

                self.apos.docs.db.update({
                    workflowGuid: self.apos.launder.id(req.query.workflowGuid)
                }, {
                    $push: {
                        comments: comment
                    }
                }, {
                    multi: true
                }, function (err, lol) {
                    if (err) {
                        return res.json({
                            status: 'error'
                        })
                    }
                    console.log(lol);
                    return res.json({
                        status: 'ok'
                    })
                });

                // docs.forEach(doc => {
                //     doc.comments.push(comment);
                //     self.apos.modules['comments']
                //         .update(req, doc, {
                //             permissions: false
                //         }, function () {
                //             console.log("Doc Update :", doc);
                //             return res.json({
                //                 status: 'okay'
                //             });
                //         });

                //     // Then should update the module here using .update()
                // });
            });
    })
```

Comment: How are you inserting the piece, exactly?

Comment: By normally click "Add Comment Form" and make new title for it with admin permission(For example : Portfolio Comment). After that,  on page, i select comment widget and browse "Individually" search Portfolio Comment to display the widget on that page. So when I did create piece with admin permission and when update with permission false, it conflict saving the piece? That's my problem? Do you want me snapshot on step by step how do I create the piece? I gladly like to do so

Comment: How is the actual portfolio comment being inserted in the database? That is the code I need to see.

Comment: Oh OK I see it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well , I think Tom Boutell was right . Draft and Live mode is a different docs. However , I can't access my public comments data unless I do `excludeTypes` as below code. Now I understands , If you want to submit your form or comments or likes pieces WHILE using your Apostrophe-Workflow . In live mode , you can access the data if you set this on your app.js file :

```js
    // WORKFLOW
    'apostrophe-workflow': {
      excludeTypes: ['comments' , 'likes' , 'contact-form'],
      alias: 'workflow'
    },
```

[image]

> Then I can access all LIVE when trying to submit any form in LIVE mode ! So when using Apostrophe-Workflow , makes sure that you set any `types` or `properties` to exclude it for accessing data in LIVE MODE . If you submit your form in draft mode , you only get those data in draft mode , never in LIVE mode. And it will prompt you to `submit/commit` everytime you submit the form. You don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

If you directly manipulate a document in the live locale, this is not pushed back to the draft locale. In apostrophe-workflow content flows from draft to live, not the other way around.

In general, if you're going to attach comments to a doc as an array property, then you should be using mongodb directly and utilizing the `$push` operator, rather than going through Apostrophe's model layer. This avoids race conditions if two people attempt to submit comments around the same time.

And if you want the comments to exist in both draft and live locales, then you should use `doc.workflowLocale` to identify it to MongoDB, rather than using `doc._id`, and make sure you pass `{ multi: true }` to `apos.docs.db.update`, like this:

```
apos.docs.db.update({
  workflowGuid: self.apos.launder.id(req.query.workflowGuid)
}, {
  $push: {
    comments: comment
  }
}, {
  multi: true
}, function(err) {
  // respond to the browser here
});
```

However, array properties are not a great way to implement comments. MongoDB has a document size limit, and loading hundreds of comments no matter what every time you open the doc is not going to be a good performance strategy. You should look at using a separate piece type for the comments and joining them.

An important note: if you are using workflow to achieve localization as well, then you will probably want to limit an update query like this to just, for instance, `en` and `en-draft`, not all locales. Or not, but be mindful that it will impact many languages if you do not.

Comment: Wow , this is surely an advance stratergy code that I do not know about apostrophe-workflow . I agree with that performance hit when requesting a page with thousands of comments ! But I think we both know that ,we all need a comment feature as part of ApostropheCMS's project. Although , thank you SO MUCH for helping me with this code. I can see much clearer now on how performance hit does play a big role in this . Hopefully others are finding this question & answers are helpful.

Comment: For most users, it makes much morse sense to use Disqus! However I understand that certain types of private sites can't use that because Disqus can't access the page.